# In Tableau, is there a way to only show the first and last date in the table output using the date filter

Tags: date, tableau-api

Tableau will generally show every single date within table output of the date ranges filtered for. Is there a way to only show the first and last date in the table for the date of ranges selected?

I created an image of the desired output in excel. Link below:

[Desired output example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hy04G.png)

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The feature that will address your goal is called a Level of Detail (LOD) calculation. They have many uses and take various forms. I suggest reading about the in the online help.

But, to answer your question, the LOD calc to find the first (i.e. minimum) value in a date field called, say, Transaction Date, is;

```
{ MIN([Transaction Date]) }
```

The formula for the latest value is left as an exercise for the reader

Comment: You're welcome. Welcome to Stack Overflow. The customary thank you is to both accept and upvote the answer to your question. Hope you enjoy learning and using Tableau.